# Creating a simple login with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, mvc, angular.js

I'm brand new to AngularJS. I would like advice as to whether I'm approaching the design of a simple login section of an app built with Angular correctly.

The app consists of two view partials: *login.html* and *user-admin.html*. Of what I have so far, the user types their username into the login page. A controller checks if that username is listed in *users.json* file, if so then login is successful and the *user-admin.html* partial replaces *login.html*.

I feel that the controller which checks the typed username against the usernames in *users.json* could be written better. Is there a more efficient way than using the 'for' statement?

To develop this further I will want to add some way of preventing a logged in user seeing the login page and a non-logged in user seeing the admin page. My initial thought is to use cookies. But would the 'Angular' way be to create a service that perpetuates the logged in status between views? If that is the best way to implement it, what would that service look like?

### app.js

```
angular.module('userApp', ["ngResource"]).

config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',   controller: LoginCtrl}).
        when('/loggedin', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-admin.html', controller: UserCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}],[ '$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;
}]).

factory("User", function($resource) {
    return $resource("users/:userId.json", {}, {
        query: {method: "GET", params: {userId: "users"}, isArray: true}
    });
});
```

### controllers.js

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, User) {
    $scope.users = User.query();
    $scope.loginUser = function() {
        var loggedin = false;
        var totalUsers = $scope.users.length;
        var usernameTyped = $scope.userUsername;

        for( i=0; i < totalUsers; i++ ) {
            if( $scope.users[i].name === usernameTyped ) {
                loggedin = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( loggedin === true ) {
            alert("login successful");
            $location.path("/loggedin");
        } else {
            alert("username does not exist")
        }
    }
}

function UserCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.logoutUser = function() {
        $location.path("/login");
    }
}
```

### users.json

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "name": "Tommy",
        "password": "123456",
        "log": {
            "registration": "2012.12.14",
            "lastLog": "2013.01.15"
        }
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "name": "Anne",
        "password": "123456",
        "log": {
            "registration": "2012.12.24",
            "lastLog": "2012.12.29"
        }

    },
    {
        "userId": 3,
        "name": "Miles",
        "password": "abc",
        "log": {
            "registration": "2013.02.01",
            "lastLog": "2013.02.01"
        }
    }
]
```

### login.html

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<section>
    <form ng-submit="loginUser();">
        <label for"userUsername">Username</label><input type="text" id="userUsername" ng-model="userUsername">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: do you have a working example fo this?

Comment: No unfortunately I don't. I didn't get much further with this project and hasn't been worked on for a while.

Comment: change line: for( i=0; i < totalUsers; i++ )  TO  for(var i=0; i < totalUsers; i++ )

Answer (score 6):

There is much wrong with your code..

- You are iterating over every record to find a username, what happens if you have lots of users ?
- You are not verifying the password !?
- It seems like you are exposing the REST services with all the user id's and passwords !?
- It seems that if the user knows the `/loggedin` URL, then the user can skip logging in since you do not validate `loggedIn` anywhere. Even worse, `loggedIn` is a variable local to LoginCtrl.

It is good to try and write everything yourself, it brings valuable experience. But please, use this only for throwaway websites.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create an HTTP call to a PHP `$http.post();` to make your call in a secure php file and getting a query to spit back a `json_encoded();` response. I liked the example above. I will be using it along with some ngCookies to keep the session open that way.

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of mistake with your code:

1. The database seems to be limited
2. Your code is not authenticating the username and password